# Plotting logarithm with base b in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, plot, graphs

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,,x=1.3cm,y=0.4cm]
\clip(-1,-3) rectangle (12,13);
\draw [domain=0.1:10 ,smooth,very thick] plot(\x, \Log{2}{3*\x}); 
\draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (11,0.);
\draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (-1,0.);
\draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,13);
\draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: El idioma de este sitio es inglés.  The language of this site is English.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I am sorry, I do not understand Spanish, but if you are wondering that your code does not compile: `\Log{2}{3*\x}` is not a valid function to be plotted. Apart from the fact that you are not supposed `\...` here, which is appropriate for *printing* (rather than plotting) functions, by default `tikz` does not understand `\log_2`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,,x=1.3cm,y=0.4cm]
    \clip(-1,-3) rectangle (12,13);
    \draw [domain=0.1:10 ,smooth,very thick,samples=50] plot(\x, {ln(3*\x)/ln(2)}); 
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (11,0.);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (-1,0.);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,13);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could define a `Log` function yourself. (Typo fixed, big thanks to Henri Menke!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,,x=1.3cm,y=0.4cm,
    declare function={Log(\b,\x)=ln(\x)/ln(\b);}]
    \clip(-1,-3) rectangle (12,13);
    \draw [domain=0.1:10 ,smooth,very thick,samples=50] plot(\x, {Log(2,3*\x)}); 
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (11,0.);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0,0.) -- (-1,0.);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,13);
    \draw[->,color=black,line width = 0.8pt] (0.,0) -- (0,-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Log(\b,\x)=ln(\x)/ln(2);` → `Log(\b,\x)=ln(\x)/ln(\b);`

Comment: ... and there is also `log2` for this special case.